# how to add multiple values in React Native cross-cookie

Tags: cookies, react-native

I am trying to create array in cookies . so it can be updated on every click. I have created cookies but don't no  how can i add multiple values in cookies.
my code is :

```
 import cookie from 'cross-cookie';
    handlePressProduct(id) {
    cookie.set('cart', { product_id: 1234 ,qty: 1,customer_id: isuerID},{product_id: id ,qty: 2})
      .then(() => console.log('cookie set!'));


        cookie.get('cart')
      .then(value => alert(value)); 
    }
```

how can i use multiple values in cookies ?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and its working fine for me .

```
 var data = {};
         data[id] = {product_id: id ,qty: 1,customer_id: isuerID};

        cookie.set(data)
        .then(() => console.log('cookies set!'));
});     

  cookie.getAll().then(function(cookies){

     alert(JSON.stringify(cookies))

     })
```